# JDBC LockRegistry accross JVMS

Tags: spring-integration

Is my application service obtaining a lock using JDBC LockRepository supposed to run inside an @Transaction ?

We have a sample application service that updates a JDBCRepository and since this application can run on multiple JVMS (headless). We needed a global lock to serialize those updates.

I looked at your test and was hoping my use case would work too. ... [JdbcLockRegistryDifferentClientTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-jdbc/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/jdbc/lock/JdbcLockRegistryDifferentClientTests.java#L97)

My config has a DefaultLockRepository and JdbcLockRegistry;

I launched( java -jar boot.jar) my application on two terminals to simulate. When I obtain a lock and issue a tryLock() without @Transaction on my application service both of them get the lock (albeit) one after the other almost immediately. I expected one of them to NOT get it for at least 10 seconds (Default expiry).

```
Service (Instance -1) {
  Obtain("KEY-1")
  tryLock()
  DoWork()
  unlock();
  close();
 }
Service (Instance -2) {
 Obtain("KEY-1")
 tryLock() <-- Wait until the lock expires or the unlock happens
 DoWork()
 unlock();
close();
 }
```

I also noticed here [DefaultLockRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/jdbc/lock/DefaultLockRepository.java#L155)  that the transaction scope (if not inherited) is only around the JDBC operation.

When I change my service to

```
 @Transaction
    Service (Instance -1) {
      Obtain("KEY-1")
      tryLock()
      DoWork()
      unlock();
      close();
     }
```

It works as expected.

I am quite sure I missed something ? But I expect my lock operation to honor global-locks (the fact that a lock exists in a JDBC store with an expiration) until an unlock or expiration.

Is my understanding incorrect ?

Comment: Do you mean there are two records in the `INT_LOCK` for the same lock key?

Comment: Since my test involved running the same application on 2 terminals (simulating a multi JVM cluster) I suspected there to be only 1 row inside INT_LOCK (because I was using the same lock-key, region and id). I ran a test and realized that I wont see any rows because there is a deleteall at app context.close().

I added code to fetch the contents of the INT_LOCK right after I acquire the lock and right before I unlock. I noticed that the created timestamp column (there is only one row) value changed ( The other thread overwrote the row). No @Transaction in my service.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use different client ids. The same is means the same client. That for special use-case. Use different client ids as they are different instances

Comment: I started with that (letting it use a default client-id) and I should have mentioned it; Sorry.  I also should mention this works as I expected when I add @Transaction to my service( the lock row is locked for the duration). Client-1 (instance) acquires and goes on sleep for 30 seconds and then releases. Client-2 started at the same time is able to acquire the same lock. I also don't see any queries in the DefaultLockRepository to make it work outside of "@Transaction". Maybe Clients using DefaultLockRepository should always start a transaction?

Comment: If they use different `id`, they can't acquire the same lock, the query is `id`-based, and `INT_LOCK` table has a `primary key (LOCK_KEY, REGION)` constraint.

Answer (score 0):

This works as designed. I didnt configure the DefaultLockRepository correctly and the default ttl was shorter than my service (artificial wait) lock duration. My apologies. :) Josh Long helped me figure this out :)

Answer (score 0):

The behavior here is subtle (or obvious once you see how this is working) and the general lack of documentation unhelpful, so here's my experience.

I created a lock table by looking at the SQL in `DefaultLockRepository`, which appeared to imply a composite primary key of `REGION`, `LOCK_KEY` and `CLIENT_ID` - **THIS WAS WRONG**.

I subsequently found the SQL script in the `spring-integration-jdbc` JAR, where I could see that the composite primary key **MUST BE** on just `REGION` and `LOCK_KEY` as @ArtemBilan says.

The reason is that the lock doesn't care about the client, obviously, so the primary key must be just the `REGION` and `LOCK_KEY` columns.  These columns are used when acquiring a lock and it is the key violation that occurs should another client attempt to obtain the lock that is used to restrict other client IDs.

This also implies that, again as @ArtemBilan says, each client instance must have a unique ID, which is the default behavior when no ID specified at construction time.